# Correct use of ListIndex navigate form by query

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a subform that has a query in a combo box, and I want to navigate through the different records matching the query results.

Online, I found the "ListIndex" function for a combo box, and my code is as follows for a "next record" scenario:

```vb
Private Sub Button_Click()
    comboCountry.SetFocus
    If comboCountry.ListIndex <> comboCountry.ListCount - 1 Then
        comboCountry.ListIndex = comboCountry.ListIndex + 1
    Else
        comboCountry.ListIndex = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

Even though my initial query works to get in a finite number of values into the combo box, when I press the button I get the error:

> Run-time error 7777; You've used the ListIndex property incorrectly

VBA Debugger says that the erroneous line of code is line 4,

```vb
comboCountry.ListIndex = comboCountry.ListIndex + 1
```

What is going wrong with my macro?

Thanks

Comment: I dont see anything wrong in the macro. It might be due to some setting on the properties of the combo.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the on-line help - which you can access by one key press - is very clear: *This property is read-only*.

You can do something like this:

```
If comboCountry.ListIndex < comboCountry.ListCount - 1 Then
    comboCountry.Value = comboCountry.ItemData(comboCountry.ListIndex + 1)
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the source of your faulty code comes from another web site (maybe bytes?). I am not sure but I guess it is different in excel vba than in access vba. At least in ms access vba, listindex is read only and combo.value = combo.itemdata (i) is what is used to set the selections.

below is the code used to cycle through combobox list items using arrow keys.

```
Public Sub ArrowKeys(ByRef KeyCode As Integer, combo As ComboBox, ByRef Flag As Boolean)
' flag is used to be able to toggle normal action in combo_change()
Select Case KeyCode
    Case vbKeyDown
        KeyCode = 0 ' make sure the action wont be duplicated
        If combo.ListIndex <> combo.ListCount - 1 Then
          combo.Value = combo.ItemData(combo.ListIndex + 1)
          Flag = True
          combo.Dropdown
        Else
          combo.Value = combo.ItemData(0)
          Flag = True
          combo.Dropdown
        End If
   
   Case vbKeyUp
        KeyCode = 0 ' make sure the action wont be duplicated
        If combo.ListIndex = -1 Then ' In case nothingg is selected yet (-1 index)
          combo.Value = combo.ItemData(combo.ListCount - 1)
          combo.Dropdown
        ElseIf combo.ListIndex <> 0 Then
          combo.Value = combo.ItemData(combo.ListIndex - 1)
          Flag = True
          combo.Dropdown
        Else
          combo.Value = combo.ItemData(combo.ListCount - 1)
          Flag = True
          combo.Dropdown
        End If
End Select
End Sub
```